# Joining todos and their completions in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, relationship, models

i have the following models:

```
class Todo
has_many :completions

class Project
has_many :completions

class Completion
belongs_to :todo
belongs_to :project
```

(all projects share the same todos)

What would be the best approach to return **all** todos and match them with their completion(s) for a given project on GET /projects/:id/todos?
I was thinking about iterating and setting a virtual attribute in the controller, but there has to be a simpler way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use has many through association.

```
class Todo
has_many :completions
has_many :projects, through: :completions
scope :completed, ->{ where(completed: true) }

class Project
has_many :completions
has_many :todos, through: :completions
```

Then you can retrieve all completed todos from a project.

```
project = Project.find_by(id: params[:id])
todos = project.todos.completed
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your reply, but wouldn't this just return the todos that have a completion? i want all of them, and the completion as an attribute if existing, nil otherwise

Comment: I've edit my answer. There I supose you have a boolean attribute `completed` that determines if todo has been completed.

Comment: not exactly: the completions should be the indicator whether a todo for a project has been completed or not. if one exists => true (completion as attribute for todo), if not false. appreciate your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

did it like this

```
@todos.each do |t|
  t.completion = Completion.where(:todo_id => t.id).where(:project_id => 1).first
end
```